# Same Bulk API Query success at local but failed after deploy to Airflow

Tags: query, bulk-api

I have tried all the ways to debug the code, also check the library version between my local machine and server, they are same.
Following is the query success at local:
sfdc query:

```
SELECT Id,OwnerId,Name,CurrencyIsoCode,CreatedDate,CreatedById,
    LastModifiedDate,LastModifiedById,SystemModstamp,LastViewedDate,
    LastReferencedDate,RelatedRecordId,ResourceType,IsActive,
    IsCapacityBased,IsOptimizationCapable,LastKnownLocationDate,
    LocationId,ServiceCrewId,FSL__Efficiency__c,FSL__GanttLabel__c,
    FSL__Online_Offset__c,FSL__Picture_Link__c,FSL__Priority__c,
    FSL__Travel_Speed__c,Last_Punch_Date_Time__c,Last_Punch_T__c,
    Last_Time_Sheet_Entry__c 
FROM ServiceResource
```

Same query which called by bulk API on airflow I got following error:
InvalidBatch :

> Failed to process query: INVALID_FIELD: LastKnownLocationDate,LocationId,ServiceCrewId,FSL__Efficiency__c
> ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:256 No such column 'ServiceCrewId' on entity 'ServiceResource'.
> If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I am not sure what can be the issue, the only difference is my local is mac and airflow been deployed on kubernetes linux.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Two possible changes between your local and server process.

1. Check if api versions are same. Some fields are valid only in certain versions.
2. Check if user that issuing the soql in server has access to that field

Comment: Sorry, for get to mention, I am using the same api user in my local and airflow Also I have check the library version are same between my local and airflow server: server.simple-salesforce                    1.11.2 and salesforce-bulk                      2.2.0

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).